# How prevent Jackson from serializing a field in a third party class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Heres a question for Jackson 2.3 I don't have the possibility to change to other frameworks.

I want to serialize objects to json using Jackson 2.3.
Some of the Objects are from a third party library implementing a particular (external) interface.
What I want to achieve is to prevent certain fields in those objects to be serialized.
I do not have access to modifying this class so @JsonIgnore wont cut it.
Heres an example

```
    public interface ThirdParty{
      public char[] getPassword();
      public String getUser();
      public Department getDepartment();
    }
```

I'm new to Jackson, but have a feeling that it should be fairly simple to do something like this

```
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("DemoModule",VersionUtil.versionFor(this.getClass()));
    testModule.addSerializer(ThirdParty.class, new Some_Serializer_That_Can_Ignore_Password()));
    mapper.registerModule(testModule);
```

(I don't think there is something called a Some_Serializer_That_Can_Ignore_Password, what I want is something that does NOT serialize the field)
I would prefer not to write a lot of code to make it work, I've seen quite verbose examples for older versions of Jackson, but none for Jackson 2.3.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use jackson mixins: [somewhat obsolete documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations), [issue about obsolete documentation with examples for jackson 2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/issues/2), [SO search for jackson mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jackson+mixin).

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer for the original question, but I found a way that worked for excluding particular types, this code ensures that any `StackTraceElement`s are not serialized.

```
    SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("DemoModule", VersionUtil.versionFor(this.getClass()));
    testModule.addSerializer(StackTraceElement.class,new JsonSerializer<StackTraceElement>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(StackTraceElement value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider){/*Do not serialize*/}
    });
    mapper.registerModule(testModule);
```

Comment: It can still be sort of a winner, through that logic you can at least make the serialization of the third-party objects tailor made; in stead of excluding what you don't want you can include what you do want. But that would be a last resort as it is terrible micromanagement and thus a huge bother to maintain.